# Acquiring a submitted form name

Tags: perl, cgi

Almost embarassed to ask but since it's such a basic form manipulation issue I *ought* to know about...

Is there a Perlish way of acquiring a submitted form name so that I may differentiate between differing forms or am I going to have to use hidden fields for this purpose?  (hidden fields was the only Google result I could find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Browsers do not send the `name` of a form in HTTP requests.

It exists only for use with client-side scripting (and is obsoleted by `id` and `class`).